# Get details of RAID configuration on Linux

Tags: linux

How to get the details of RAID configuration in Linux ?

Comment: Better asked on http://linux.stackexchange.com

Comment: server-related question would better go on http://serverfault.com/ There are more sysadmins lurking around there:)

Comment: Questions about Linux are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139271/how-to-get-details-of-raid-devices-both-soft-and-hard

Answer (score 18):

`mdadm -D /dev/mdxx` will give you detail of raid configuration.
`cat /proc/mdstat` will give detail about raid algorithm,level and chunk size etc .

Comment: what about hardware raid?

Comment: @om-nom-nom :behavior of these command is same with hardware or software raid in linux.

Comment: I really doubt so -- mdadm only mentions **software** raid and in my particular case unsurprisingly fails to perform any tasks on machine with hardware raid (CentOS 6.2)

Comment: @om-nom-nom: yeah, i was wrong. mdadm only works for software raid. In case of hardware raid vendor should provide customized raid management tool. It could be based on command line,BIOS or GUI.

Answer (score 10):

This is real if this RAID is sofware....
In case of RAID hardware, you could type this command :

```
lspci -vv | grep -i raid

01:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2208 [Thunderbolt] (rev 01)
        Kernel driver in use: megaraid_sas
        Kernel modules: megaraid_sas
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're talking about a running array:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

If you're talking about the mdadm config file, it's usually in /etc or /etc/mdadm depending on the distribution you're running on.  The following command should find it in any event:

```
find /etc -name '*mdadm*'
```

**ETA**: Also, I would *strongly* recommend that you carefully study the mdadm man page so that you are very familiar with that utility.  Knowing that utility well ***will*** save your bacon at some point.

Answer (score 1):

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
```

(or whatever /dev/mdXXX you are using)